# Cannot find module mysql - error

Tags: mysql, node.js, module

I have installed nodejs and mysql(also the work bench)

I am building a server using nodejs and mysql.

in my code I write:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var TEST_DATABASE = 'nodejs_mysql_test';
var TEST_TABLE = 'test';
var client = mysql.createClient({
  user: 'root',
  password: 'root',
});

client.query('CREATE DATABASE '+TEST_DATABASE, function(err) {
  if (err && err.number != mysql.ERROR_DB_CREATE_EXISTS) {
    throw err;
  }
});
```

and the compiler gives me an error:

> Error: cannot find module 'mysql'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think that i solved it.

there is a folder node_modules under the nodejs folder
in that folder there is a mysql folder.
copied it to the folder that from there i am running my program,
and i t works:)

Answer (score 13):

This happens when you don't have the module installed, so go to the root of your project and install node-mysql:

```
npm install mysql
```

You don't need to manually copy the folder yourself, dependencies are best handled with NPM.

Comment: Totally did not realize that it had to be in the project directory.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1. Goto your project folder.... in my case
   [image: command prompt command]
2. type as show in screenshot

> npm install mysql

3. After installation you will see the following directories.
   [image]